# SAPUI5 get all registered users for a specific subaccount

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I've a SAPUI5 Fiori application
I need to get all the cloud tenant users from SAP Cloud Platform for a specific Sub Account.

Currently, from User API I can get only logged in user details.
https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/1de599bf722446849d2b2e10132df42a.html

Is there any way to do that

Comment: Please check, if it works with this service:
URI: https://<tenant ID>.accounts.ondemand.com/service/scim/Users/
Users Search:
The user search method of the Identity Authentication implementation of the SCIM REST API protocol allows you to perform a request for user search. 
User search is implemented as defined by the System for Cross-domain Identity Management (SCIM) protocol for querying and filtering resources.

Please see also the [corresponding docu](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6d6d63354d1242d185ab4830fc04feb1/Cloud/en-US/3af7dfae0aad4cf79ab8d822f8322e76.html).